# Continuous colour gradient within line segments in vector layer

Tags: vector, line, color, stream

I am new to QGIS (using version 3.13) and my main objective with it is creating a line vector (multiple points, representing a river) in which the colour of the line changes based on a Continuous Attribute (colour gradient **within** line segments). It is about plotting the changes in the concentration of chemicals in a river (from hereon the "proxy"). I tried with R, SAGA and QGIS.

In QGIS I tried the following:

1. Layer/Add layer/Delimited Text Layer, attributes: Long/Lat/River(name)/SequenceNumber in the river (1-7 points)/pollutant concentration (continuous variable, not integer). Gives points plot.
2. Convert points to a line, with Points to Path and Saga-version Points-to-Line(s), same output, order field SequenceNumber, Group Field RIver. Everything OK, a line vector with lines of different colour.

See image in which I try to explain some things.

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to couple the line vector to the attribute Proxy (continuous variable). In the attributes form of the line vector (symbolism/colour categorized option), I cannot select this proxy (only the river name, a discrete parameter), which is normal. I would need the "graduated colour" of the vector but this brings to me a "value" field that I don't know how to handle. Anyway, the desired Proxy is not in the attributes form of the line vector, so it seems that this is not the way to go.

On page (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_attribute_data.html) it is explained how to use continuous colour symbols. Here Symbology includes Legend Type: Continuous Color and allows to select the desired proxy (in the example, HEIGHT). I tried using an earlier QGIS version (2.12) but I was not able to reproduce this. Maybe this is because the example uses a colour gradient to indicate contour lines where hence every line has only one colour. It is stated that this approach is useful as:

> The GIS Application will use a numerical attribute value from a
> feature (e.g. contour heights or pollution levels in a stream) to
> decide which colour to use.

but the example given (HEIGHTS) has a really different nature that the pollution example, so it doesn't help.

In a probably very relevant Q&A ([Styling line layer based on two attributes in QGIS ? (1 discrete and 1 continuous)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168418)) the answer of user MarHoff is:

> If you only got one discrete attribute (road type [IN MY CASE RIVER
> NAME]) and one pseudo-continuous attribute (number of lane) I think
> you don't even need to use the rule-based renderer which is the way to
> go if you got more complex situations.

So, the way to go for me is probably the "rule-based renderer" but I don't know how to do this or prepare the data so that it can be done.

And with the Geometry Generator (creating polygons from the line) I think it is not possible to link colours to the Proxy.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but you could use Join Attributes by Location to attach the Proxy value from the points layer to the line layer. You can then use the Proxy value in the value field of your graduated symbol.