# QGIS 3x setting scale-based label opacity

Tags: qgis, labeling

I would like to decrease the opacity of my layer when zooming out.

I prepared something like this:

```
 Case
 When @map_scale>1750 Then (1 - transparency) * 255
 End
```

It doesn't work.

The similar thread is here:

[How to set transparency per polygon in a shapefile in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165956/how-to-set-transparency-per-polygon-in-a-shapefile-in-qgis)

but applies to the shapes

How to make the scale-dependant label transparency?

Comment: Are we talking about total label transparency, or only the background?

Comment: Where do you use this condition?

Comment: Also, what is "transparency"? An attribute column? If so, what are its contents? Furthermore, why are you multiplying by 255?

Comment: I mean label opacity

Comment: First tab of Edit (lable) rule has an Opacity slider

Comment: I know, but I need the rule for the certain scale. When I move slider it will be applied for all conditions regardless scale, name, etc

Answer (score 4):

Apply the following query for the opacity of labels in the Expression String Builder (Expected Format: `int[0-100]`)

```sql
CASE
WHEN @map_scale> 750 THEN 20
END
```

*Map Scale: 1:578*

[image]

*Map Scale: 1:1157*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The expression for label opacity based on scale:

```
if(@map_scale>1750, 50, 100)
```

The expression for polygon fill opacity based on scale:

```
color_rgba(255, 0, 0, ( 1 - if(@map_scale>1750, 0.5, 0)) * 255)
```

Now both the labels and polygon fills are 50% transparent if you zoom out of the 1:1750 scale. The different syntax is caused by the fact that label opacity is a value in range [0, 100], while polygon fill is constructed as an RGB alpha color.